# How to print values retrieved from data model in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

How can I retrive values from  my rails3 model and display it on console. 
 I tried the below code which display some Hash value.
 Do suggest me how to display individual values of model.

```
@links = Domainurl234.all
puts @links
```

Comment: Are you looking for how to get a hold of a specific attribute? like @links.attribute_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use each method to print individual values of @links

```
@links = Domainurl234.all
@links.each { |link| p link }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply load the object (you dont need the @, tahts for instance variables only) and then you can access the attributes in object orientated style.

```
object=Model.find(<id>)
object.attribute_name
```

If you dont know the attributes of `Model` you can simply write down the models name and the attributes will be displayed.